# Does Inspiring Sword (Divine Fighting Technique) affect the user?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

The relevant effect of the feat reads as follows:

> While wielding a longsword, you can perform an impressive display of prowess as a full-round action. All allies within 30 feet who can see your display gain a +2 sacred bonus on attack rolls, saving throws, and skill checks for 1 round + 1 round per 5 points of base attack bonus you have.

Will the user of this feat also benefit from the sacred bonus?

I ask because it is a bit similar to a Bard's performance in that "All allies in X range that can see/hear the performance" benefit from it, though that one does affect the Bard itself.

Comment: For the cost of a full-round action, you better do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> While wielding a longsword, you can perform an impressive display of prowess as a full-round action. All allies within 30 feet **who can see your display** gain a +2 sacred bonus on attack rolls, saving throws, and skill checks for 1 round + 1 round per 5 points of base attack bonus you have.
>
> Will the user of this feat also benefit from the sacred bonus?

Yes, **if** you consider being able to see parts of your own body as "see[ing] your display" - a qualification easily handled with a mirror around. Without it, you might have to take the position that you see the display because you see where you are putting your feet and arms during the display. It's not unreasonable, but it could qualify as "impossible" if the DM decides that seeing the totality of the display is required to gain the benefit.

The [PFFAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nda) offers the following:

> *Ally: Do you count as your own ally?*
>
> **You count as your own ally unless otherwise stated or if doing so would make no sense or be impossible. Thus, "your allies" almost always means the same as "you and your allies."**

Comment: So basically: "yes unless your DM decides it makes no sense"

Comment: @AnneAunyme - Yes, but I hesitate to edit in such a simple statement because, while it is technically very right, it is an answer that could technically apply to every single question asked. When an answer is so broad it can answer every question, it's effectively too broad to answer any question.

Comment: Don't edit, your answer is fine! It is "basically" what I summed up but not only, and that's why it is a good answer and not a lame unspecific one.